# Which layout/template adopt with jQuery

Tags: jquery, templates, layout

When creating jQuery UI based websites, CSS, JS and HTML code can be splited into components:

1. which frameworks use for templating/splitting components?
2. what are the benefits and drawbacks of server side generated pages VS client side JSON calls?
3. how to define a navigation through components?
4. eclipse for development and firebugs for debugging are they enough good tools for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Backbone.js](http://backbonetutorials.com/) is the kind of tool I was searching for. Its MVC approach helps to split an application into pieces.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)
2. Depends on the remit of the application.
3. See 2.
4. Firebug is invaluable.

For clarification or more specific answers please expand your questions so they include appropriate levels of detail